# Need to communicate with child process to process a file

Tags: c#, process, ipc, named-pipes, memory-mapped-files

I have several 3rd party DLLs which are super flaky. They can sometimes hang and never return or sometimes throw weird exceptions which can bring down the whole process.

I want to move these DLLs and load then in a separate Child process. That way instead of having to do nasty Thread.Abort I can just bring down the process cleanly and later re-spawn it when required.

So my parent application receives a list of files that need to be processed by certain third party DLLs. I essentially need to pass these to the new child process, let it process the file and then communicate back to the parent that it was successful. I must also be able to bring down the process if sh*t hits the fan and re-spawn. These files come as constant stream so spawning a process every-time i get a file is not possible, id want it to hang around and just accept requests.

Right now i'm spawning the child process from the parent and then attempting to use Memory Mapped Files to share the files/work. Would it be easier just passing the location of said file and somehow getting a response when its processed?

What would be a good strategy here...

Answer (score 0):

I would....

Create a WCF service, using PerCall instancing that hosts the dlls and does the file process - this would spawn a new instance for each call and if any goes down it should not affect the other. You could host it even as part of your main app but maybe as a separate Windows service, and as its probably going to be on the same machine, use named pipes transport.

Fire each request at it from your main app.

If you don't get a successful response (as long as its not a wcf exception - i.e. endpoint not found) just retry the request for x number of times